# Drupal: jquery update module... is possible to replace jQuery files in it?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Drupal jquery_update module to use a more recent version of jQuery.

I've enabled the module and the jQuery file included in its folder is used. However it is still old: min.1.2.6.js

So, I've tried to replace it with min.1.3.2, by replacing the file in the jquery update module "replace/" folder.

Unluckily I get some bugs in the the back-end, when I click on available updates, a lightbox is triggered. See picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/drupal-LightBox.png

Is possible to use jQuery 1.3... (or even better 1.4) on Drupal 6 ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified on the [jQuery Update module page](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update),

> - "Stock" Drupal 6.x
>
>   - jQuery 1.2.x
> - jQuery Update **6.x-1.x**
>
>   - jQuery 1.2.x (currently 1.2.6)
> - jQuery Update **6.x-2.x**
>
>   - jQuery 1.3.x (currently 1.3.2)

If your Drupal core is up to date, 6.x-1.x won't do anything for you.  You'll have to install 6.x-2.x to update jQUery to 1.3.2.  You can either install the [latest alpha release](http://drupal.org/node/779956) or [the latest development snapshot](http://drupal.org/node/409588).

Comment: Thank you for that ! What is sad is that they have not released a stable version yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to jQuery 1.4+ You're gonna probably want to follow the instructions specified in the following link to disable the upgrade on the admin panel:  [Fix Drupal Admin Panel after installing jQuery Update Module](http://www.widgetsandburritos.com/technical/programming/drupal-admin-jquery-update-module/)

Answer (score 1):

you also just replace the files in /modules/jquery_update/replace with whichever version you want to use. Just make sure to go to admin/settings/jquery_update and choose the type of file.

Comment: i noticed the above method may cause issues when trying to edit existing views if you try and use jquery 1.4. For me 1.3 worked well with all modules and views.